# ASP.NET Core gRPC works locally but not in Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, kubernetes, grpc

I setup my ASP.NET Core project to use gRPC. I have a server and a client.

Locally, it is working fine. But when I deploy to Docker, the client cannot call it anymore.

Is there anything wrong with my settings below?

**Server**

*Startup.cs*

```
//Configure Services
services.AddGrpc();

...

//Configure
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<ProgramService>();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

*appsettings.Dev.json*

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "gRPC": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:8000",
    "Protocols": "Http2"
  }
}
}
```

*Dockerfile*

```
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 8000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8000
```

*kubernetes deployment.yml*

```
containers:
        - name: tenant-api-grpc 
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
```

*kubernetes service.yml*

```
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
        - name: "8000"
          port: 8000
          targetPort: 8000
```

**Client**

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddGrpcClient<Tenant.Proto.Program.ProgramClient>(o =>
            {
                o.Address = new Uri(Configuration["ServiceUrlConfiguration:ServiceTenantUrl"]);
            });
```

*appsettings.Dev.json*

```
"ServiceUrlConfiguration": {
    "ServiceTenantUrl": "http://tenant-api-grpc-svc.dev.svc.cluster.local:8000/"
  }
```

Comment: What's the error log?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error log is this: Status(StatusCode=\"Unavailable\", Detail=\"Error connecting to subchannel.\", DebugException=\"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at

Comment: here i find error i was getting https://github.com/wicharypawel/net-core-grpc-errors also check https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html

Comment: Are you deploying your client or your server or both?

Comment: I am deploying Both

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to analyze your porblem with the given information.

I would suggest to check the base url. When you start server and client in kestrel you find the services under localhost. If you deploy the services using docker-compose the services find each other under the name of the service respectively. If you deploy the containers independently, you can access localhost from within the container using host.docker.internal.